# Configuring CodeQL with Github actions using well known weaknesses

Tags: github-actions, codeql

I am new to CodeQL and therefore my apologies if my question is an obvious one, however, I've been unable to understand a few simple concepts.

Firstly, I can easily configure a public repo with a github action using a yml file configured as follows:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    # The branches below must be a subset of the branches above
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  analyze:
    name: Analyze
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      actions: read
      contents: read
      security-events: write

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        language: [ 'java' ]
        # CodeQL supports [ 'cpp', 'csharp', 'go', 'java', 'javascript', 'python', 'ruby' ]
        # Learn more about CodeQL language support at https://aka.ms/codeql-docs/language-support

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Initializes the CodeQL tools for scanning.
      - name: Initialize CodeQL
        uses: github/codeql-action/init@v2
        with:
          queries: +security-extended
          languages: ${{ matrix.language }}
          # If you wish to specify custom queries, you can do so here or in a config file.
          # By default, queries listed here will override any specified in a config file.
          # Prefix the list here with "+" to use these queries and those in the config file.

          # Details on CodeQL's query packs refer to : https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning#using-queries-in-ql-packs
          # queries: security-extended,security-and-quality


      # Autobuild attempts to build any compiled languages  (C/C++, C#, or Java).
      # If this step fails, then you should remove it and run the build manually (see below)
      - name: Autobuild
        uses: github/codeql-action/autobuild@v2

      # ℹ️ Command-line programs to run using the OS shell.
      #  See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

      #   If the Autobuild fails above, remove it and uncomment the following three lines.
      #   modify them (or add more) to build your code if your project, please refer to the EXAMPLE below for guidance.

      # - run: |
      #   echo "Run, Build Application using script"
      #   ./location_of_script_within_repo/buildscript.sh

      - name: Perform CodeQL Analysis
        uses: github/codeql-action/analyze@v2
```

As indicated in the yaml file, I'm using Java as the language.   What I'm trying to then do is trigger a failure / alert with a simple code such as this in Java.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Example code for https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/476.html
        String cmd = System.getProperty("cmd");
        cmd = cmd.trim();
    }
}
```

This simple code is an example from Common Weakness Enumeration (CWE) 416 where I'm trying to dereference a variable that hasn't been defined.

If I go to Security -> Code scanning alerts it will show that the scanning was performed but not alerts were found.

Basically, I'm wondering if I need to initialize the CodeQL with a specific CWE under the Initialize CodeQL step in the yaml file.

[image: Code scanning no alerts screenshot]

Comment: I investigated specifying packs (https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning#using-codeql-query-packs) which I believe are still beta at this stage.   However, this would result in a failure where the workflow was not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeQL only has a [specific set of queries](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/java/), which do not cover all possible CWEs. [This list](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/java-cwe/) shows the currently covered CWEs for Java.

As far as I know there exists no query at the moment which detects the specific issue you are showing in your question (there are however [queries which detect derefencing `null`](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/java/java-dereferenced-value-is-always-null/)). The reason for this is most likely that it would be difficult to prevent false positives. For example if your application is started with `-Dcmd`, then the system property would not be `null`. Similarly there could be a call to `System.setProperty` in a different part of the application which sets the system property to a non-`null` value.

Besides that you have configured `queries: +security-extended` but the type of the query you are looking for (assuming it existed) would most likely be in the [query suite `security-and-quality`](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning#using-queries-in-ql-packs) because it is not directly security related.

You could also try to [write your own queries](https://codeql.github.com/docs/writing-codeql-queries/about-codeql-queries/) and then [include them in the code scanning workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning#specifying-additional-queries). Some concepts of CodeQL might feel a bit unfamiliar at first, but they provide great examples and tutorials for getting started. However, you should probably first check if the provided queries already suffice for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Since May 2022:

- [Using CodeQL query packs](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning#using-codeql-query-packs) (and its [associated CWE coverage](https://codeql.github.com/codeql-query-help/codeql-cwe-coverage/), with [query specifiers](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-cli/analyzing-databases-with-the-codeql-cli/#example-query-specifiers)) is still beta, but not going anywhere
- its setup has been simplified:

> ### [Code scanning can be set up more easily without committing a workflow file to the repository](https://github.blog/changelog/2023-01-09-code-scanning-can-be-set-up-more-easily-without-committing-a-workflow-file-to-the-repository) (Jan. 2023)
>
> Code scanning's new default setup feature automatically finds and sets up the best CodeQL configuration for your repository.
> This will detect the languages in the repository and enable CodeQL analysis for every pull request and every push to the default branch and any protected branches.
> Default setup currently supports analysis of JavaScript (including TypeScript), Python, and Ruby code.
> More languages will be supported soon, and all [other languages supported by CodeQL](https://codeql.github.com/docs/codeql-overview/supported-languages-and-frameworks/) continue to work using a GitHub Actions workflow file.
>
> The new default setup feature is available for CodeQL on repositories that use GitHub Actions.
> You can use default setup on your repository's "`Settings`" tab under "`Code security and analysis`" (accessible by repository admins and security managers).
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/19343236/210406786-60bfdf35-2022-4e0e-823a-24e7553497d3.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of code scanning's new default setup]
>
> The options to set up code scanning using an Actions workflow file or through API upload from 3rd party CI/CD systems remain supported and are unchanged.
> **This more advanced setup method can be useful if you need to alter the default configuration, for example to include custom query packs**.
> Default setup configurations can also be converted to advanced setups if your analysis requirements change.
>
> Default setup is currently available at the repository level.
> We are actively working on future features at the organization level so you can easily set up code scanning at scale across large numbers of repositories.
>
> This has shipped to GitHub.com and will be available in GitHub Enterprise Server 3.9.
> To learn more, read the documentation on [setting up code scanning for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/setting-up-code-scanning-for-a-repository).

In your case, you would still need an Actions workflow file, to specify a query pack.